# "Before it hardened" or "Before it hardens"?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-simple, present-simple

Which one is the correct sentence?

a) Please eat the toffee **before it hardens**.

b) Please eat the toffee **before it hardened**.

Comment: Hi user4084. Please remember to "make an effort to research your question before posting it". This should not be a website for simply getting other people to answer your homework questions for you. You have asaked a very straightforward question about English tenses. As an English language learner, you should be able to at least try to work it out for yourself and demonstrate that attempt in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you are being told that sentence by another person who is asking you to eat the toffee in its current state before it gets into another state which is to become hard.

But "hard" is an adjective, and in your sentence, it takes the forms of a verb which is "harden".

So, as the toffee didn't become hard **yet**, and the request is in the **present tense**, that makes the first sentence the correct one:

> Please eat the toffee before it hardens.

You can say "hardened" in the following form, but the meaning would differ:

> Please eat the toffee because it hardened.

Answer (score -1):

In between these two sentences, **a** is the correct one.

**b** needs to be corrected like this:

> Please eat the toffee before it ***gets*** hardened.

The latter part of the sentence, after "before" , should be constructed in the present tense anyway.

Comment: You have mixed verb tenses in your sentence "gets" is present tense and hardened is past tense. You also should have used the adjective form "hard" -- Please eat the toffee before it gets hard.